# GRUB2 shows "trying to terminate EFI services again"

Tags: grub2, uefi

A few days ago my ubuntu 17.04 software updater on a dual boot system with windows 10 ran some automatic updates and prompted a reboot. Ever since, after I select my boot option in GRUB there's a black pop-up window with the text "trying to terminate EFI services again".

Except for the visual hindrance and taking a few more seconde, booting works fine. However, I'm very curious as to what causes this error and I'd like to fix it. Help or an explanation is very much appreciated.

Comment: Same here! I just got the update yesterday and it did the same thing. There was also some screen flickering before I chose my boot option.

Comment: Potentially relevant bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1748896